# Why does the freezeWeights fucntion not work for me in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am following the mathswork tutorial for transfer learning on the GoogLenet, and when it comes to the freezeWeights function, it just doesn't work for me, and I am copying the function execution of the tutorial word for word here. It doesn't give me a proper error message either, just says

[image]

I have no clue why it isn't working. Am using a mac and MatLab version R2021b. Any ideas why it won't work?

Edit:
Link to tutorial I am following -
[MatlabTransferLearning](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/train-deep-learning-network-to-classify-new-images.html)

Comment: Just edited the post @SardarUsama

Comment: Have you installed the Deep Learning Support Model for GoogleNet from the Add-Ons Explorer? And did you open the whole page inside Live Editor and run all sections in order? It works fine with me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't actually downloaded any add-ons, I didn't realise I needed any as I thought the googlenet architecture was already accessible on matlab. I just called it by doing net = googlent at the start of the code. What do I need to do download the deep learning support model? @AboAmmar

Comment: On the Home tab you will find the `Add-Ons` icon click the arrow and choose `Get Add-Ons`, then in the search box write `Deep Learning Toolbox Model for GoogLeNet Network` you will get the first result with about *7.7k Downloads* just choose that and click `Install`. Go back to the tutorial page and run everything in the Live Editor.

Answer (score 0):

For this example to work in your computer you need to copy some scripts to your current working directory. These scripts can be found in your MATLAB examples directory.
Script names:

- findLayersToReplace.m
- createLgraphUsingConnections.m
- freezeWeights.m

Path where you find these scripts (if you installed "Deep Learning Toolbox Model for GoogLeNet Network")

Documents\MATLAB\Examples\R2023a\nnet\TransferLearningUsingGoogLeNetExample